# Shortened Firebase dynamic link not working with prefilled Google Forms link

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-forms, firebase-dynamic-links, url-shortener

I am using the following google apps script to generate a shortened Firebase dynamic link.  The URL is a link for a pre-filled Google form.  When executed, I get the following message: "Unrecognized param 'entry.2058899362' and the shortened link does not contain the parameters.  I can't change the format of these parameters...this is what Google needs to display the form with entries.  Any ideas on how I can generate a shortened URL with these parameters?  When I manually create the shortened link in Firebase, it does work.

```
    function getShortenedUrl(){   
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScChyiL-L1LJCyASi8lpYBVqljMJQVRgk-LMJ0bt1wFdT94mA/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.2058899362=Capitol&entry.2019483203=Duck,+Donald";

    var req = 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=mykey';
    var formData = {
    "longDynamicLink": "https://mydomain.page.link/?link=" + url,
    "suffix" : {
    "option" : "SHORT" 
     }
    };
   var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
   'payload': JSON.stringify(formData) 
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(req, options);
    var res = JSON.parse(response);
    return res.shortLink;
    }
```

Thanks for your time.